# Why the result is incorrect to find 3-cliques using networkx in Python?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to find all 3-cliques using networkx's find_cliques method. However, there should be far more than 2 as the result shows. Please help me to figure out why.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
edges_fig_4 = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('a','e'),
           ('b','c'),('b','d'),('b','e'),
           ('c','d'),('c','e'),
           ('d','e'),('e','d'),
           ('f','b'),('f','c'),('f','g'),
           ('g','f'),('g','c'),('g','d'),('g','e')]
G.add_edges_from(edges_fig_4)
cliques = nx.find_cliques(G)
cliques3 = [clq for clq in cliques if 3<=len(clq)<= 3]

print(cliques3)
```

Comment: Did you check the [`find_cliques` documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html)? The function doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Yes. It said "Search for all maximal cliques in a graph."Note that maximal is not maximum. And he also cited the publication to find all maximal cliques. It should list all maximal cliques at different k values.

Comment: The 3-cliques you're expecting to find are not maximal cliques.

Comment: Hi @user2357112-supports-monica, the documentation link is broken or inaccessible.

Comment: @Mello: [It moved.](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the document, `find_cliques` returns all maximal cliques. In your case there are cliques with size greater than 3 (`abcde`)(`cdeg`) and you will need to also have all possible 3-combination in that bigger clique. This is because each sub-clique of a clique is also a clique but it's not maximal.

EDIT: You will also need use set to avoid overlapped cliques.

Use the following code:

```
import itertools
cliques3 = set(sum([list(itertools.combinations(set(clq), 3)) for clq in cliques if len(clq)>=3],[]))
```

Alternatively, using `enumerate_all_cliques` will also give cliques of size (cardinality) `k = 1, 2, 3, ..., maxDegree - 1`. See the document here: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? Could you modify my code to realize my goal?

Comment: It should be itertools.combinations()

Comment: Sorry, you will also need to actually iterate over it.

Comment: Not quite. `cliques3` isn't defined. Also, avoid loops and use `[list(itertools.combinations(clq, 3)) for clq in cliques if len(clq)>3]`

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks, now I know the pythonic way to do that.

Comment: This is still not right, the nested structure seems to have some problems.

Comment: That is so pythonic...I prefer your original version.

Comment: You got the idea. I'll try to figure out how to make this answer prettier in case anyone else need it.

Comment: one thing for your original answer, I note that when len(clq)>3 has 14 cliques; while len(clq)>=3 has 16; I count that the correct one is 14; why is that?

Comment: That's because you also have two 3-cliques that are maximal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76796/discussion-between-haochen-wu-and-peterxwl).