# Efficient way for finding all the complete subgraphs of a given graph (Python)?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is there an efficient way for finding all the fully-connected components (i.e. the complete subgraphs) of a given (undirected) graph with networkx? For example, I have the following adjacency matrix (without self-loops):

```
    |0 1 1 0 0|
    |1 0 1 0 0|
G = |1 1 0 1 0|
    |0 0 1 0 1|
    |0 0 0 1 0|
```

which corresponds to the following graph [image]
The code should return the following tuples of nodes:

```
(0,1), (1,2), (0,2), (3,4), (2,3), (0,1,2)
```

I know networkx has routines for finding cycles, strongly-connected components, etc, but I cannot find anything about **fully-connected** components. If it's not possible with networkx, it would also be fine with Numpy + Scipy. Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is what I did:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools


def findsubsets(S, m):
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))



A = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])


G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)

M = np.sqrt(np.size(A))


for m in range(2, M+1):

    for a in findsubsets(range(0, M), m):

        if(nx.number_of_edges(G.subgraph(a)) == (m**2 - m)/2.):

            print nx.nodes(G.subgraph(a))
```

which basically finds all the possible mXm subgraphs of the given one, and then checks if they have the maximum (i.e. (m**2 - m)/2) number of connections. But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that, because the performance of the function `itertools.combinations` is not very good for large graphs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's simply `list(nx.find_cliques(G))`, just because I didn't know that in graph theory a clique is a fully connected subgraph.

**EDIT**

More precisely, `list(nx.find_cliques(G))` finds the maximal cliques, therefore it's not what I need. I found a similar post at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010752/why-the-result-is-incorrect-to-find-3-cliques-using-networkx-in-python).

So the correct answer is to use `list(nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G))`. However, this function returns also cliques of size 1, which I don't like since I don't have self-loops in my graph. Therefore the final solution is to use the following line of code:

```
[s for s in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G) if len(s) > 1]
```

Comment: Why do you need the `list`?  You should be able to iterate over the result directly.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. In my case the entries of the graph G represent the intersection among rectangles in a plane (so G[i,j] = 1 if rectangles i,j overlap, and zero otherwise). The cliques here represent the sets of overlapping rectangles (e.g. a clique of size 3 represents the intersection among 3 rectangles). Basically I need the whole list in order to know who overlaps who, because I want to assign a different color to each intersection area. Things slow down too much if I iterate with a for loop, therefore I'm trying to vectorize my code as more as possible.

Comment: I mean that `[s for s in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G) if len(s) > 1]` should do exactly the same thing.  You're materializing the result of `enumerate_all_cliques` into a list and then iterating over that.  As an aside, using a listcomp isn't what people usually mean when they refer to vectorization.

Comment: Oh cool now I understand, you're right! I edit the post again, thanks!